# Find number of map methods launched during map stage in MapReduce Word Count Example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I came across a MapReduce WordCount sample application and I want to edit the code so that it also outputs the number of times the Map method is called during the map stage. I have two text files and this is the code that I am using for the application

```
public class WordCount 
{
public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

This is just for learning purposes so I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop already counts number of map method calls. You can see it in application UI in counters section or get from job after it finishes:

```
int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

String group = "Map-Reduce Framework";
String counter = "Map input records";

long val = job.getCounters().getGroup(group).findCounter(counter).getValue();
```

Remember that this number can be bigger than number of input file lines if speculative execution is enabled.

Comment: So I just need to add this code to my main method? @AdamSkywalker

Comment: @useruser1412 yes